# Разреженные массивы

Tags: javascript

> Разреженными называют массивы, индексы элементов которых не образуют непрерывную последовательность чисел, начиная с 0. В них значение свойства length больше количества элементов.

```
new Array(12); // Создаст разреженный массив?
               // Он ведь вроде только под одно условие подходит, 
               // так как в нем нет не элементов не индексов, а length 12.
[0,1,2,3,,,,]; // А такой массив разреженный? 
               // Ведь последовательность индексов от 0 до 3 четкая, 
               // а после нет индексов. Снова только одно условие совпадает.
```

Comment: и в чем вопрос?

Comment: Непрерывные последовательности не образуются, предполагается, что последовательность длинной равной длине массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Array(12); // Создаст разреженный массив!`

Подходит под оба условия:

1. значение свойства length больше количества элементов
2. индексы элементов не образуют непрерывную последовательность чисел.

`[0,1,2,3,,,,]; // Такой массив разреженный!`

Подходит под оба условия:

1. значение свойства length больше количества элементов
2. индексы элементов не образуют непрерывную последовательность чисел.

---

Чтобы стало понятнее можно дополнить второе условие словами: до *length-1* включительно.